# How to work with PostGIS types using EntityFramework6.Npgsql?

Tags: postgresql, entity-framework-6, npgsql

We are working with the following technologies, all latest as of this writing:
1) EntityFramework6.Npgsql (3.1.1)
2) Entity Framework (6.1.3)
3) Npgsql (3.2.1)

I've spent about a day researching, but had trouble finding a definitive answer about whether I can use EntityFramework6.Npgsql with PostGIS data-types: geography(POLYGON, 4326) and geography(POINT, 4326).

With what is currently available, what is the recommended way to read/write these data-types in Postgres via Entity Framework? I would be happy even if a work-around is available. I strongly prefer an Npgsql solution, as this provider is already deeply integrated into the rest of my project.

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: EntityFramework6.Npgsql does include spatial support, although I'm not very familiar with how things work. I think you're going to have to use System.Data.Spatial and DbGeography, an SqlServer example may work more or less in the same way.

Comment: Note that in EF Core you should be able to place PostGIS properties directly on your entities (e.g. PostgisPolygon). This isn't possible in EF6.x.